# Angular and google distance matrix no access control header

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=bl79yt&destinations=cw73bz&key=mykey.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

In my angular app. I have my http request to the google distance matrix like this :

```
 var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=' + pcodefrom + '&destinations=' + pcodeto + '&key=mykeyhere';
  console.log(url);
     $http({method: 'GET', url: url,headers: {
            "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
            "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
            "X-Rack-CORS": "preflight-hit; no-origin"
        }}).success(function(data) {
            };
                    }).error(function(data){

                    });
```

Ive allowed the website url in the google api console but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do because the CORS headers should be set on Google backend servers.

To avoid CORS issues you should use the distance matrix service of Google Maps JavaScript API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix